# Ruby Mechanize Alert box

Tags: ruby, web, mechanize

I'm trying to click OK on an alert box using Ruby mechanize and am having issues with it. Does anyone have a solution or link I could use for this?

Comment: **way more** details will be required for anyone to give you a good answer.

Comment: No. All I was asking is if I can use Ruby's Mechanize to click OK on alert boxes and how. I was provided an answer to my question without providing any more details as they are not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mechanize does not run any javascript so no alert boxes will ever be created.  If the site needs javascript to work properly, mechanize will not work for you.

Comment: A simple `onclick="confirm('really?')"` is safe to ignore. There's not a lot of situations where mechanize really wouldn't work.